# Ruby block to string instead of executing

Tags: ruby

Take this example:

```
write_as_string { puts 'x' }
```

I then want to be able to do

```
def write_as_string(&block)
  puts block.to_s
end
```

When I execute this, I want the output to be:

```
"puts 'x'"
```

I want to be able to receive the block and get the actual code for the block instead of executing it.

Motivation: Creating a DSL, I want to the mock to be converted into a number of other method calls, hidden from the calling code - using existing objects and methods without monkey patching them.

Any ideas on this would be great!

Thanks

Ben

Answer (score 19):

If you're on Ruby 1.9, you can use the sourcify gem. It provides Proc#to_source, which is like ParseTree's Proc#to_ruby.

When using sourcify, if you have nested procs in your source code, you might have to help it along with the :attached_to option:

```
## (Works in Ruby 1.8) Using ParseTree (with parse_tree_extensions)
block.to_ruby
## (Works in Ruby 1.9) Using sourcify
block.to_source
## Try this if you get Sourcify::NoMatchingProcError or Sourcify::MultipleMatchingProcsPerLineError
block.to_source :attached_to => :name_of_block_in_source_code
```

I posted about [ParseTree and Ruby 1.9](http://numbers.brighterplanet.com/2010/12/17/replacing-parsetree-in-ruby-1-9) in my company's blog.

Comment: I had luck with the source_method gem for Ruby 2.1.2 (which pry includes as a dependency so was already available in our test infrastructure where I needed it). I have a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675053/printing-the-source-code-of-a-ruby-block/36654421#36654421

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate: [Printing the source code of a Ruby block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675053/printing-a-ruby-block)

```
sudo gem install ParseTree
sudo gem install ruby2ruby
```

then

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'parse_tree'
require 'parse_tree_extensions'
require 'ruby2ruby'

def block_as_string &block
    block.to_ruby
end
```

results in

```
irb(main):008:0> block_as_string {puts 'x'}
=> "proc { puts(\"x\") }"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the [ruby2ruby gem](https://github.com/seattlerb/ruby2ruby), which does this nicely.  Unfortunately, to analyze a block this gem depends on ParseTree, which is [unsupported in Ruby 1.9](http://blog.zenspider.com/2009/04/parsetree-eol.html).

Comment: That seems cool. But given the following example, I need to somehow get the defined block as a string. How could I do this?  

 ruby      = "def a\n  puts 'A'\nend\n\ndef b\n  a\nend"
    parser    = RubyParser.new
    ruby2ruby = Ruby2Ruby.new
    sexp      = parser.process(ruby)

Or have I missed something?

Comment: if you're not concerned about 1.9 compatibility, i'll recommend @mletterle's answer.