# Can I access the source of a ruby block without &block?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

I am using Pry under Ruby 2.5 to debug a problem within a base class (`Net::HTTP`)

I am getting an exception caused by an HTTP 404 response and I want to examine the body of the request that was made. To do this I want to inspect the block which was passed to `start`, but the `start` method does not have a parameter, it's called using `yield`:

```
Frame type: method

From: /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb @ line 910 Net::HTTP#start:

    905: def start  # :yield: http
    906:   raise IOError, 'HTTP session already opened' if @started
    907:   if block_given?
    908:     begin
    909:       do_start
 => 910:       return yield(self)
```

Using [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) is there any way to view the source of a block, if that block is not passed in a `&block` parameter?

Saw [Printing the source code of a Ruby block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675053/printing-the-source-code-of-a-ruby-block) but it doesn't help me because I don't have a method parameter to use here.

Comment: As a hacky workaround, you could edit this file and change it to take the block as an explicit parameter (`&blk`) - that way you could call `.to_ruby` on it

Comment: Thanks @maxpleaner. I think I solved the `Net::HTTP` problem that triggered this question but I am still interested in the best way to inspect a block, ideally without having to edit gems or distro-provided ruby files.

Comment: Spoke too soon! Looks like I'll have to edit the source of the gems I'm using which make `Net::HTTP` calls...

Comment: If you're ever really stuck, don't forget you can patch out elements of `Net::HTTP` with your own methods that can intercept, inspect, report, and do other things with arguments and results. This can be very handy when debugging third-party libraries that are harder to navigate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the real issue here is that I didn't read all the [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) help (specifically rescue-pry) and didn't know about the `up` command...

```
Usage: up [OPTIONS]
  Go up to the caller's context. Accepts optional numeric parameter for how many frames to move up.
  Also accepts a string (regex) instead of numeric; for jumping to nearest parent method frame which matches the regex.
  e.g: up      #=> Move up 1 stack frame.
  e.g: up 3    #=> Move up 2 stack frames.
  e.g: up meth #=> Jump to nearest parent stack frame whose method matches /meth/ regex, i.e `my_method`.

    -h, --help      Show this message.
```

By executing `up` within a `pry` session from a raised exception, I was able to get to the block where the exception was raised and inspect the local variables I needed.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** You can try to utilize [Kernel#caller](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller).

---

Let's consider a file called `foo.rb`:

(this example uses `byebug`, but the flow with `binging.pry` is almost the same)

```rb
1: require 'byebug'
2: 
3: def bar
4:   byebug
5: 
6:   yield
7: end
8: 
9: bar { 'some string' }
```

When we run this file with `ruby foo.rb`, we will be stopped at the `byebug` statement.

```rb
[1, 9] in foo.rb
   1: require 'byebug'
   2: 
   3: def bar
   4:   byebug
   5: 
=> 6:   yield
   7: end
   8: 
   9: bar { 'some string' }
```

Then we can execute `caller` and something like the following will be printed:

(output is intentionally reduced and formatted)

```
(byebug) caller
[
  "~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.0.1/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:97:in `process_commands'",
  "~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.0.1/lib/byebug/processors/command_processor.rb:55:in `at_line'",
  "~/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.0.1/lib/byebug/context.rb:98:in `at_line'",
  "foo.rb:6:in `bar'",
  "foo.rb:9:in `<main>'"
]
```

As you can see, `caller` returns the current execution stack as an array containing strings in the form `file:line` in `method'.

The last string in this array specifies where `bar` was called.

Knowing this information you can open the file with that `bar` call and track which block was passed into it.

(`foo.rb:9` in this particular case)

Hope that helps.

As a bonus, there is an amazing article by [Tenderlove](https://github.com/tenderlove) - [I am a puts debugger](https://tenderlovemaking.com/2016/02/05/i-am-a-puts-debuggerer.html), where you can find a solution probably for every Ruby debugging problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Using Pry is there any way to view the source of a block, if that block is not passed in a &block parameter?

Your problem is twofold: you have to 1) get the implicit block and 2) print its source.

For 1) you can simply call [`Proc.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Proc.html#method-c-new) within the method's context to get its block argument as a proc.

So instead of:

```
def foo(&block)
  # ...
end
```

You could also retrieve the block via:

```
def foo
  block = Proc.new
  # ...
end
```

For 2) you could use the [sourcify](https://github.com/ngty/sourcify) gem:

```
require 'sourcify'

prc = Proc.new { |i| i * 2 }
prc.to_source
#=> "proc { |i| (i * 2) }"
```

---

Applied to your problem:

```
# foo.rb
require 'pry'
require 'sourcify'

def foo
  binding.pry
end

foo { |i| i * 2 }
```

```
$ ruby foo.rb

From: foo.rb @ line 6 Object#foo:

    4: def foo
 => 5:   binding.pry
    6: end

[1] pry(main)> block = Proc.new
#=> #<Proc:0x00007f9373b1c368@foo.rb:9>

[2] pry(main)> block.call(123)
#=> 246

[3] pry(main)> block.to_source
#=> "proc { |i| (i * 2) }"
```