# How to read the contents of a Ruby Proc to a String

Tags: ruby

I have the following setup in Ruby 2.6.3:

```
def some_method(&block)
   @block = block
end

some_method do
   puts "Hello There!"
   puts "General Kenobi"
end
```

I need to take the proc that comes out of `some_method` and extract the literal code that was passed in the given block, in this example I would ideally get:

```
"puts \"Hello There!\"\n puts \"General Kenobi\""
```

as a String, so I can evaluate the passed code at a later date. However, it seems that every way I could find to do this went out the window after Ruby 1.9 (parse_tree and ruby2ruby being the primary methods). In previous iterations of this project where I've had to do similarly weird things with Procs, I've been able to use the `source_location` of the passed proc to figure out the content well enough to achieve this. Unfortunately I can no longer rely on the proc having a legitimate source location for this to work.

My question is this: **Is there any way in modern Ruby that I would be able to simply get the interior of this proc, the source of which does not reliably exist**?

While looking for some way to figure this out I've come across the `RubyVM::InstructionSequence` class and have been able to use this to infer the following about the proc in question:

```
# Continuing from the first example
obj = RubyVM::InstructionSequence.of(@block)
puts obj.disasm

=> == disasm: #<ISeq:block in __pry__@(pry):7 (7,12)-(10,3)> (catch: FALSE)
== catch table
| catch type: redo   st: 0001 ed: 0014 sp: 0000 cont: 0001
| catch type: next   st: 0001 ed: 0014 sp: 0000 cont: 0014
|------------------------------------------------------------------------
0000 nop                                                              (   7)[Bc]
0001 putself                                                          (   8)[Li]
0002 putstring                    "Hello There!"
0004 opt_send_without_block       <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0007 pop
0008 putself                                                          (   9)[Li]
0009 putstring                    "General Kenobi"
0011 opt_send_without_block       <callinfo!mid:puts, argc:1, FCALL|ARGS_SIMPLE>, <callcache>
0014 nop
0015 leave                                                            (  10)[Br]
```

Looking at this I can clearly see the instructions to load and run the given code, but, particularly with more complicated process, it is not something I can, nor want to, reliably deserialize. So a follow up question would be: **Is there any way to cleanly deserialize these RubyVM::InstructionSequence instructions**?

Comment: This answer might still work with 2.6.x https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654421/5615759

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing the source code of a Ruby block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675053/printing-the-source-code-of-a-ruby-block)

Comment: No, it looks like this is returning the same thing as Proc#source which is part of core now. Unfortunately in this case it recognizes the source as either the method calling it or a stringified version of the Proc itself