# Converting math expression to string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
problem = 7 + 3
puts problem.to_s
```

I'm new to Ruby. The code above returns `10`. How do I get `7 + 3` as the output, without assigning it to `problem` as a string in the first place? Am I missing something extremely simple?

Comment: _"I'm new to Ruby"_ – well, this is how evaluation and assignment works in virtually any programming language: the _result_ is being assigned. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Stefan: if I were to guess, a simple "solve this equation" game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 is `Fixnum` (ruby < 2.4) or `Integer` (ruby >= 2.4)

"7" is `String`

So you need to define for ruby what you need because `+` for `Integer` is addition, `+` for `String` is concatenation:

```rb
problem = "7" "+" "3"
```

That is equal to:

```rb
problem = "7+3"
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me, unfortunately. As I stated in the question, I want to keep `problem` in num + operator + num form for use in other parts of my program.

Comment: `eval(problem)` for calculating string. But that is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637431/16236820)

Comment: Got you. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @tNJipNJR Welcome on SO! Do not forget to accept answer that was useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing something extremely simple?

Yes, you are. This is impossible. `7 + 3`, as an arbitrary expression, is evaluated/"reduced" to `10` when it's assigned to `problem`. And the original sequence of calculations is lost.

So you either have to start with strings (`"7 + 3"`) and `eval` them when you need the numeric result (as @zswqa suggested).

Or package them as procs and use something like [`method_source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36654421/125816).

Answer (score 1):

just for fun (don't try at home)

```rb
class Integer
  def +(other)
    "#{self} + #{other}"
  end
end

problem = 7 + 3
puts problem.to_s # "7 + 3"
```

Comment: No need for that `.to_s`, though. Also, don't try it at work. :)

Comment: This answer is correct, reflects the only way to obtain the desired result and illustrates the folly of doing so. I like.